# Sqlite3 insert data in database does not work in c

Tags: c, database, sqlite, prepared-statement

```
   sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
   sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "INSERT INTO links(NAME, LINK, SIZE, STARRED)  VALUES ('?' , '?', ? , 0);", 41, &stmt, NULL);
   if(stmt != NULL) {
      sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, name, 0, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
      sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, link, 0, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
      sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 3, size);
      sqlite3_step(stmt);
      sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
   }else{
     printf("%sError during insertion in the database%s\n", RED, RST);
   }

  sqlite3_close(db);
```

I always get on the output `Error during insertion in the database` but can't understand why, maybe something related to `sqlite3_prepare_v2` but doesn't know what, I tried to execute the query 'manually' with random data and it works.

Comment: I'm not an expert on how C uses prepared statements, but I think that the `?` placeholders should not be enclosed inside single quotes.

Comment: @forpas just tried `sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "INSERT INTO links(NAME, LINK, SIZE, STARRED)  VALUES (?, ?, -1 , 0);", 41, &stmt, NULL);` and it doesn't work anyway

Comment: @forpas trying with '?' insert ? in the field, while trying with ? as you rightly say, try to insert name and link, but actually, in the database, I have empty values (this not happen in for the integer), do you know why?

Comment: As I said I don't know how this works in C, but in other languages `'?'` is not considered a placeholder which will be replaced by the parameters that you bind. It is considered as the char `'?'` and this is what is inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the zSql statement is 69 characters. It is is better to us -1 for length as by default it will be null-terminated string and size is automatically computed :

```
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "INSERT INTO links(NAME, LINK, SIZE, STARRED)  VALUES (?, ?, ? , 0);", -1, &stmt, NULL);
```

Do not forget the 3rd '?' in the statement for the 3rd argument.
Edit : write it as ? in the statement

Comment: The third argument is integer I didn't think it needed the quote, by the way the third arguments is actually the one corrected inserted, that's what is on my database: https://i.imgur.com/LHUSech.png and I get this if even I put `sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, "test", 0, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);`
      `sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, "link", 0, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);`

Comment: Ok, as unspoken fixed with `sqlite3_bind_text (stmt, 1, "test", -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);`

Comment: For future code and maintenance it may be better to use parameter names in statement : sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "INSERT INTO links(NAME, LINK, SIZE, STARRED)  VALUES (:name, :link, :size , 0);", -1, &stmt, NULL); and then use sqlbin_parameter_index(stmt, ':name'),... instead of 1,...

Answer (score 1):

You bind twice  item 2 of the statement and ? is missing for item 3.

Comment: You right! I tried to change to 3, but unfortunately not work as well (by the way thanks! I'm going to edit the question)

Answer (score 0):

Just solved by changing the third parameter of `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` that is the maximum length of zSql in bytes, and 47 is to small.